# How to close alert message pop-ups

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two test cases:

**FYI - IF I RUN THESE TWO TEST CASES INDIVIDUALLY, BOTH WORK.**

1. Script enters data in the text field and clicks on the update button, alert message pops-up and is closed by the script. Success!
2. Script enters data in a different text field and clicks on the same update button, the same alert pops-up. At this time, alert pop-up is not closed. The test fails, and the following error is thrown:

> java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.AssertionError: expected [false] but found [true]

These are my two test cases:

1

```
// locate an element field to get default impressions
    WebElement defaultImpressions = driver.findElement(By
            .name("campaignImpScheduled"));
    defaultImpressions.clear();

    // send non-numeric characters
    defaultImpressions.sendKeys(scheduledImpNumbersNonNumericCharacters);

    // verify that the Update button is clicked
    verifyDisplay("Update Button ===> is clicked", By.id("updateCamSchBtn"));
    // click the Update button
    driver.findElement(By.id("updateCamSchBtn")).click();

    // verify text in the alert message
    verifyDisplay("You have made following changes :"
            + " ===> alert box appears", By.id("over"));

    // check the checkbox "Don't Prompt Me Again"
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#setcookie")).click();

    // verify that the checkbox is checked
    verifyDisplay("The checkbox is ===> checked", By.id("setcookie"));

    // verify that the continue button is clicked
    verifyDisplay("Continue Button ===> is clicked",
            By.id("continueButton"));
    // click on the continue button
    driver.findElement(By.id("continueButton")).click();

    // get an element of the error message alert window
    driver.findElement(By.id("errorM"));

    // verify the alert message
    verifyDisplay(
            "'"
                    + scheduledImpNumbersNonNumericCharacters
                    + "'"
                    + " ===> is an invalid value for field: 'Scheduled Impressions'.",
            By.xpath("//div[@class='processerror']//div[@class='closeicon']"));

    // verify that the alert message window is closed
    verifyDisplay(
            "The alert message window ===> is CLOSED",
            By.xpath("//div[@class='processerror']//div[@class='closeicon']"));
    // close the error window
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//div[@class='processerror']//div[@class='closeicon']"))
            .click();
```

2

```
// locate an element for the scheduled clicks field
    WebElement schClicks = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath(".//*[@id='searchid2']"));

    // clear the default value
    schClicks.clear();

    // send numerical values
    schClicks.sendKeys(scheduledClicksNumbersNonNumericCharacters);

    // verify that the Update button is clicked
    verifyDisplay("Update Button ===> is clicked", By.id("updateCamSchBtn"));
    // click the Update button
    driver.findElement(By.id("updateCamSchBtn")).click();

    // verify text in the alert message
    verifyDisplay("You have made following changes :"
            + " ===> alert box appears", By.id("over"));

    // check the checkbox "Don't Prompt Me Again"
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#setcookie")).click();

    // verify that the checkbox is checked
    verifyDisplay("The checkbox is ===> checked", By.id("setcookie"));

    // verify that the continue button is clicked
    verifyDisplay("Continue Button ===> is clicked",
            By.id("continueButton"));
    // click on the continue button
    driver.findElement(By.id("continueButton")).click();

    // get an element of the error message alert window
    driver.findElement(By.id("errorM"));

    // verify the alert message
    verifyDisplay(
            "'"
                    + scheduledClicksNumbersNonNumericCharacters
                    + "'"
                    + " ===> is an invalid value for field: 'Scheduled Impressions'.",
            By.xpath("//div[@class='processerror']//div[@class='closeicon']"));

    // verify that the alert message window is closed
    verifyDisplay(
            "The alert message window ===> is CLOSED",
            By.xpath("//div[@class='processerror']//div[@class='closeicon']"));
    // close the error window
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//div[@class='processerror']//div[@class='closeicon']"))
            .click();
```

The complet trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.AssertionError: expected [false] but found [true]
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at com.an.oas.TestBase.verifyDisplay(TestBase.java:255)
at com.an.oas.campaign.CampaignSchedulingAndBilling.schClicksEnterNumbersAndNonNumericCharacters(CampaignSchedulingAndBilling.java:274)
at com.an.oas.campaign.test.CampaignSchedulingAndBillingTest.enterScheduledClicksWithNumericsAndNonNumericCharacters(CampaignSchedulingAndBillingTest.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1220)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: What is the `verifyDisplay` function? And what's the complete stack trace?

Comment: @Louis verifyDisplay is an Assertion. And I added the trace above. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may occurs if after the first test some "ghost" window is exists in the system. Then the second test will try to close this "ghost" instead the one you expected. This explain why the tests are work separately. Please verify that after the tests no hidden windows remain in the system.